# How to realize error traceback in Emacs?

Tags: debugging, emacs, ocaml, traceback

I am writing a compiler in Ocaml. The tracback works well when I compile and test it with `make` in a terminal, for instance:

```
export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b
./Simpler-Basic test.sib
Fatal error: exception Match_failure("interp.ml", 45, 21)
Called from file "interp.ml", line 97, characters 72-86
Called from file "list.ml", line 74, characters 24-34
Called from file "interp.ml", line 108, characters 9-35
Called from file "main.ml", line 54, characters 4-17
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

But when I compile and test it in my Emacs by `Meta-x compile` followed by `make`, it does not show the traceback part in the buffer:

```
make
export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b
./Simpler-Basic test.sib
Fatal error: exception Match_failure("interp.ml", 45, 21)
make: *** [all] Error 2

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Sat Jun 18 19:03:04
```

There is a part in my `.emacs` to do traceback that I copied from a friend: http://paste.ubuntu.com/628838/

Could anyone tell me how to amend my `.emacs` so that it shows traceback as in a terminal? Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where did you write `export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b`?

If you wrote this in a makefile (↹ stands for a tab):

```
↹export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b
↹./Simpler-Basic test.sib
```

then it doesn't work because each makefile command is executed in a separate shell, so the environment variable assignment vanishes after the first line completes. You can combine the two lines in a single logical line instead:

```
↹export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b; \
↹./Simpler-Basic test.sib
```

If you always want backtraces when running an Ocaml program from within Emacs, set the environment variable in your `.emacs`:

```
(setenv "OCAMLRUNPARAM" "b")
```

In order for Emacs to recognize the backtrace messages as error messages with a location, you need to register them in [`compilation-regexp-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Mode.html#Compilation-Mode). Put something like this in your `.emacs` (untested):

```
(eval-after-load "caml"
  (add-to-list 'compilation-regexp-alist
               '("\\(^Raised at\\|Called from\\) file \"\\([^"\n]+\\)\", line \\([0-9]+\\)"
                 2 3)))
```

Comment: Indeed, i wrote `export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b` in Makefile... I have amended it and now it shows well the traceback in Emacs... One advantage to have them in Emacs is to be able to localize them by clicking on them. But this does not work yet, I guess i need to modify again `.emacs`, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: By the way, when there is something wrong with my programs during compilation, I could localize them by clicking on them, for instance I could press on `File "interp.ml", line 45, characters 21-91:`. But it does not work yet with traceback...

Comment: @SoftTimur: You need to tell Emacs how to recognize the backtrace messages, see my edit.