# OCaml bugs during why3 usage

Tags: debugging, ocaml, porting, why3

I'm trying to compile why3ide (why3-0.81) with krakatoa & jessie (why-2.33) for Windows (Cygwin). Everything went fine except I can't make right bottom textbox to show notations (it is always empty), moreover I get the error (highlighted in the picture) every time when I try to select the item to proof.
[image: why3ide on Windows]
Image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39984835/why3ide/error_capture.jpg

Here is this error:

```
Apply transformation introduce_premises
Why3ide callback raised an exception:
anomaly: End_of_file

Backtrace:
Raised at file "format.ml", line 197, characters 41-52
Called from file "format.ml", line 425, characters 8-33
Called from file "format.ml", line 440, characters 6-24
```

How can I debug this error?
(I'm newbie for OCaml)

format.ml file is here:
[cygwin/lib/ocaml/format.ml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39984835/why3ide/format.ml)

Files that refers to introduce_premises transformation are here:
[why3-0.81/drivers/gappa.drv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39984835/why3ide/gappa.drv)
[why3-0.81/src/ide/gmain.ml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39984835/why3ide/gmain.ml)
[why3-0.81/src/transform/introduction.ml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39984835/why3ide/introduction.ml)
[why3-0.81/drivers/mathematica.drv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39984835/why3ide/mathematica.drv)

P.S. I tried to add why3 & why3ide tags for this post, but my reputation is not enough for that yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trace error of OCaml programs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396738/how-to-trace-error-of-ocaml-programs)